# Node Webkit Detect Program Focus Event

Tags: focus, node-webkit

#### Is it possible to detect when a user focuses on the program, like doing an `alt-tab` to the program?

I do get the `window.onfocus` when the window is being selected, but when I have the window minimized, then I don't receive anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the NW.js [Window API](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Window)

```
// Load library
var gui = require('nw.gui');

// Reference to window and tray
var win = gui.Window.get();

win.on('focus', function() {
  console.log('Window is focused');
});
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it does not appear to work when the window is minimised.